# Why is the following inequality with the indicator variable true?

Tags: probability, statistics

Why does $$\mathbb{E} \big[ I_{\big(\frac{X-\mu}{\delta \sigma}\big)^2 \geq 1}\big] \leq \mathbb{E} \big[\big(\frac{X-\mu}{\delta \sigma}\big)^2\big]$$ where $I$ is the indicator random variable. This is a step in a proof of Chebyshev's inequality given on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_{Y\geq 1}\leq Y$ for any non-negative random variable $Y$, since the left hand side is non-zero only when $Y\geq 1$. Then take expectations on both sides.